# Phpmyadmin: Error when visiting localhost/phpmyadmin session start

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using Ubuntu and I can't open phpmyadmin, when I visit it on localhost, it displays an error

[image: [1]]
when I try running

> sudo chmod 777 to /var/lib/php/session

OR

> chown -R root:root /var/lib/php/session

it outputs

> chmod: cannot access '/var/lib/php/session': No such file or directory

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it as simple as the difference between `session` and `sessions` in the directory structure you're modifying vs the configuration file's expected path? It's either a bad copy and paste or a simple problem to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your php.ini file and look for session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session" it has to be there.
2. make sure the path exists.
3. Try clearing your browser's cache and cookies

Comment: thanks for helping me, I did check the save path it has a semicolon before it, so I remove it and it was "/var/lib/php/sessions" and I changed it to what you wrote and  I've clear the cache and changed to another browser, but it still the same error.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: can you now change the file permission tho?

Comment: yes it did change the file permission. and it is now working. Thanks very much @Karl